# How to manipulate data from json in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod

If I have this code, how do I change the age of the JSON sent from the post request and then return it?  My experience with Haskell in general is really poor so, I don't know if my problem comes from lacking of knowledge in the Yesod framework of in the language itself.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}

module Handler.Home where
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text (Text)
import Yesod


data HelloWorld = HelloWorld

mkYesod "HelloWorld" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET POST
|]

instance Yesod HelloWorld

data Person = Person
    { name :: Text
    , age :: Int
    } deriving (Eq, Show)

instance ToJSON Person where
    toJSON (Person n a)  = object
        [ "name" .= n
        , "age"  .= a
        ]

instance FromJSON Person where
    parseJSON = withObject "Person" $ \v -> Person
        <$> v .: "name"
        <*> v .: "age"

getHomeR :: Handler Value
getHomeR = returnJson $ Person "Rafael" 21


postHomeR :: Handler Value
postHomeR = do
    json_payload <- requireJsonBody :: Handler Person
    returnJson json_payload

main :: IO ()
main = warp 3000 HelloWorld
```

Comment: In general, avoid using snake case (e.g. `json_payload`) in your Haskell code

Answer (score 2):

`json_payload` is a `Person`, so you can just use the record update syntax.
For instance the value `json_payload { age = 32 }` has all the fields of `json_payload` except the `age` field which is 32.

So you can rewrite `postHomeR` as

```
postHomeR = do
  json_payload <- requireJsonBody :: Handler Person
  let modified = json_payload { age = 32 }
  returnJson modified
```

Or

```
postHomeR = do
  json_payload <- requireJsonBody :: Handler Person
  returnJson (json_payload { age = 32 })
```

The parentheses are not required but I think it makes it clearer, rather than having to go and check the syntax rules for the precedence.